# How do I pass the orderId obtained using useParams() as an ObjectId in the dispatch function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, react-redux, react-router-dom

The order details is not being fetched and the below mentioned error message is returned as payload.

**Cast to objectid failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "order**

Below is the code for the OrderScreen.js File

**OrderScreen.js**

```
const OrderScreen = () => {
  const { orderId } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [sdkReady, setSdkReady] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails);
  const { order, loading, error } = orderDetails;

  const orderPay = useSelector((state) => state.orderPay);
  const { loading: loadingPay, success: successPay } = orderPay;

  const orderDeliver = useSelector((state) => state.orderDeliver);
  const { loading: loadingDeliver, success: successDeliver } = orderDeliver;

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      navigate('/login');
    }

    const addPayPalScript = async () => {
      const { data: clientId } = await axios.get('/api/config/paypal');
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientId}`;
      script.async = true;
      script.onload = () => {
        setSdkReady(true);
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    };

    if (!order || successPay || successDeliver || order._id !== orderId) {
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_PAY_RESET });
      dispatch({ type: ORDER_DELIVER_RESET });
      dispatch(getOrderDetails(orderId));
    } else if (!order.isPaid) {
      if (!window.paypal) {
        addPayPalScript();
      } else {
        setSdkReady(true);
      }
    }
  }, [dispatch, orderId, successPay, successDeliver, order]);
```

Below is the code for the getOrderDetails action

**getOrderDetails function**

```
export const getOrderDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/orders/${id}`, config);

    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message;
    if (message === 'Not authorized, token failed') {
      dispatch(logout());
    }
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload: message,
    });
  }
};
```

**Backend code for the GET request**

```
// @desc    Get order by ID
// @route   GET /api/orders/:id
// @access  Private
const getOrderById = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id).populate(
    'user',
    'name email'
  );

  if (order) {
    res.json(order);
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error('Order not found');
  }
});
```

I did try to convert the orderId from String to ObjectId using mongoose.Types.ObjectId('oderId') but it failed too.

Comment: Best I can tell the code is correctly passing the `orderid` route path param to the `useEffect` and it is getting dispatched with `dispatch(getOrderDetails(orderId));`. It seems the issue might start when making the GET request here: `const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/orders/${Id}`, config);`. You should probably be passing the passed `id` arg. This doesn't appear to be an issue related to redux or `react-router`, but an error/issue with the backend handling the request.

Comment: It still does give the same error somehow.

Comment: Can you [edit] and include the backend code that is processing this GET request? I think the error is saying the backend either can't read or can't convert the request path parameter, a string, to the correct type the DB can consume.

Comment: @DrewReese I have added the backend code which is processing the GET request